# When diagonalizing a matrix, in what order should you arrange the the eigenvectors to form the invertible matrix $P$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, diagonalization

I was following [this example online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/107Jh.jpg) to diagonalize a matrix. It lists the eigenvectors as $\lambda =3,2,4$ (note the order). It then arranges each eigenvalue's corresponding eigenvector (3 column vectors) in the same order and puts them together to form the invertible matrix $P$ to solve $A=PDP^{-1}$.

My question is: does it matter what order the eigenvectors are put in to form $P$? Or does it not matter because $P$ will always be invertible? Or is it purely a trial and error thing?

Comment: Choose the order you please.

Comment: If the diagonal matrix goes like 4,2,3, then order the eigenvectors in the same order to construct P.

Comment: Wait, if a problem instructs us to diagonalize a matrix, then what is the point of finding $P$? By arranging the eigenvalues on the diagonal of an otherwise zero'd matrix, isn't that all it would be asking for?? What is the purpose of this $A=PDP^{-1}$ business??

Answer (score 2):

Well, based on **Maximum Ambiguity Principle** [I'm not sure if such a principle really exists :)], you can express $A$ as $$A=PDP^{-1}$$where $$P=\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&\cdots & v_n\end{bmatrix}$$and $$D=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0&\cdots & 0\\0&\lambda_2&\cdots & 0\\\vdots\\0&0&\cdots & \lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$$Since nobody has given any preference over $\lambda$s, you can choose whatever order you wish. Only don't forget to maintain the order of eigenvalues with their corresponding eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the eigenvalues in the diagonal matrix $D$ have to be the same as the order of the eigenvectors in the in the change of basis matrix $P$; i.e. the $n-$ column of $P$ is the eigenvector of of the $n-$th eigenvalue of the diagonal.